# Jenkins Agent Dockerfile: no basic auth Credentials for ECR

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I am trying to run a Jenkins stage with a docker agent built from a Dockerfile like so

```
  stage ('Build') {
      agent {
        dockerfile {
          filename '.ci/Dockerfile'
       ...
```

The Dockerfile contains the following

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY=<my registry>.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
ARG DOCKER_REPOSITORY=<my repo>
ARG DOCKER_TAG=alpine-latest

FROM ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_REPOSITORY}:${DOCKER_TAG}
```

And this throws the error `no basic auth credentials`

But I am seeing some inconsistencies. If I use the following agent

```
stage ('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
         image '<the same image from ecr>:alpine-latest'
...
```

The stage runs. Which suggests the instance has the permission to talk to ECR but they aren't getting picked up correctly by `dockerfile`. Can anyone help me solve this?